# How to change the selected tab color when clicked in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

From this method I could implement a hover that change the color when mouse over at some tab. But I need to change the color permanently when someone clicked tab.

Ex: If someone clicked Page 1, the tab should change color, if someone clicked page 2 then the tab should change color and page 1 tab should change to the color it was..

Can someone suggest a method to implement this?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.wrapper .sidebar {
  width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4b4276;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.wrapper .sidebar h2 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li {
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdb8d7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a {
  color: #bdb8d7;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .fas {
  width: 25px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover {
  background-color: #594f8d;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .main_content {
  margin-left: 220px;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h2 style="font-family: Verdana;"> Dashboard</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="page1.php"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="page2.php"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="page3.php"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="page4.php"><i class="fa fa-plug"></i> Page 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="page5.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Page 5</a></li>>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank in Advance!

Comment: a:active {
  color: red;
} 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active This is simple but using CSS

Comment: What about `href="page2.php"`? Don't you want it to redirect you to the page?

Comment: @ruleboy21 yes,need to redirect.At that page also i have included this same sidebar

Comment: Those aren't "tabs". They're menu items. Tabs are something altogether different on the web.

Comment: It sounds like you want to make the menu item for the current page have distinct styling. Is that right? That has nothing to do with clicking. It's normally done on the backend, in your PHP app, by adding a class when the route matches. You'd then implement CSS to style that class and add your hover effect.

Comment: See [Setting an active class on a menu item with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225640/setting-an-active-class-on-a-menu-item-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done on the backend but incase you don't want to alter your markup or simply wants a lazy approach, you can try something like this.

- Get the current page using `window.location.pathname`
- Select the `li a` element with the `href` value from point 1 above
- Add a class like `active` to the matched element

```js
let currentPage = window.location.pathname === '/' ? '/' : window.location.pathname.substring(1)
let pageLink = document.querySelector('.sidebar>ul>li>a[href="'+currentPage+'"]');
if(pageLink) pageLink.parentElement.classList.add('active')
```

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.wrapper .sidebar{
  width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4b4276;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  position: fixed;
  
  font-size: 15px;

  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  
}

.wrapper .sidebar h2{
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li{
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdb8d7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}    

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a{
  color: #bdb8d7;
  display: block;
  
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .fas{
  width: 25px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover{
  background-color: #594f8d;
}
    
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover a{
  color: #fff;
}
 


.wrapper .main_content{

  margin-left: 220px;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  display: block ;
  
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h2 style="font-family: Verdana;"> Dashboard</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="page1.php"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="page2.php"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="page3.php"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="page4.php"><i class="fa fa-plug"></i> Page 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="page5.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Page 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working in the answer snippet...

Comment: @Codec737 that is because the current SO page does not match any of the sidebar links. Try it locally