# I need help identifying why my bootstrap/php site code is not recognizing custom js and jquery files but the bootstrap js cdns work fine

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-5

I am working on a bootstrap, jquery/js, php, mysql site, and for some reason my custom JS files are not working properly. Right now I'm trying to add a class active with jquery script to my menu, the bootstrap cdns are working well both css and js, but my own js files aren't. The add class does not work, nor does other things I've tried with custom js files. It seems as if they were just not linked at all. I'm relatively new to php and building a site in this manner, in which certain php files are componentes, while other are pages. I'm not sure if I am just making beginners mistakes. This is my footer.php file:

```
 <footer class="site-footer text-center fixed-bottom">
            <p>&copy; 2024 PHP Site | All rights reserved.</p>
        </footer>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha512-+k1pnlgt4F1H8L7t3z95o3/KO+o78INEcXTbnoJQ/F2VqDVhWoaiVml/OEHv9HsVgxUaVW+IbiZPUJQfF/YxZw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/class-active.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is what my header.php file looks like:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?> | <?php echo $siteTitle; ?></title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="site-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" aria-current="page" href="index.php"><img class="house-img" src="img/house.png"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <li class="nav-item" id="navigation-about">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item" id="navigation-menu">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu Item</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item" id="navigation-faq">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="faq.php">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <?php
                        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
                            // If logged in, show the Logout option
                            echo '<li class="nav-item" id="navigation-logout">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
                                  </li>';
                        } else {
                            // If not logged in, show Login and Register options
                            echo '<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                        Login
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="nav-login" href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="nav-register" href="sign-up.php">Register</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </li>';
                        }
                        ?>

                    </ul>
                    <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

And what a single page looks like, about.php:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$pageTitle = "About Us";
include 'header.php';
?>



    <h1 class="text-center mt-5"><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></h1>


    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Finally the jQuery for the add class, that is not working...

```
// Use jQuery's document ready function to ensure the DOM is fully loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Attach a click event handler to the <a> tags within .nav-item
    $('.nav-item a').on('click', function() {
        // Remove 'active' class from all <a> tags within .nav-item
        $('.nav-item a').removeClass('active');
        
        // Add 'active' class to the clicked <a> tag
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

I linked all the scripts in the footer.php. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help you provide.

Comment: If you click a link, the new page will be loaded before the jquery function executes. You need to set the class after the page is loaded, not before.

Comment: ... which means, you might as well do it in PHP already, instead of via JS _after_ the page loads. https://stackoverflow.com/q/16225640/1427878

Comment: Ok i understand the issue now, it is loading before the js executes, but I thought the  $(document).ready(function() was supposed to take care of that, not sure how to set the class after the page is loaded... the php approach seems helpful but I'd like to know how to fix the issue so I can use external js/jquery files in the future... thanks

Answer (score -1):

The script was not working properly, I left the scripts in the footer as is, and modified the jquery file to include the comparison between the page url and each menu item url. Thanks for the input.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Get the current page URL
    var currentPageUrl = window.location.href;

    // Attach a click event handler to the <a> tags within .nav-item
    $('.nav-item a').on('click', function() {
        // Remove 'active' class from all <a> tags within .nav-item
        $('.nav-item a').removeClass('active');
        
        // Add 'active' class to the clicked <a> tag
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    // Iterate over each menu item link and compare its href with the current page URL
    $('.nav-item a').each(function() {
        var menuItemUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        if (currentPageUrl.includes(menuItemUrl)) {
            // Add 'active' class to the menu item corresponding to the current page
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```